# Image Link Only Partially Clickable

Tags: html, css

The issue is with my codepen project. The images are links and I want the entire image to be a link not just part of it. If you hover over the images you'll notice that the top part is unclickable. Here's the link to my codepen. https://codepen.io/creativecodepenuser/pen/MWeVyOx

Heres the HTML for my images:

```css
.project-tile img {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="projects">

  <h2>Here's links to my projects.</h2>

  <div class="projects">

    <div class="column1">

      <div class="project">
        <a class="project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/creativecodepenuser/pen/JjKEMym" target="_blank"><img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1e9AaN8ECNAKOqQ-p3KcIgN36-O6F16mv" alt="My 
    Technical Documentation Page"></a>

        <p class="project-title">Technical Documentation Page</p>

      </div>

      <div class="project">
        <a class="project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/creativecodepenuser/pen/ZEOpoPw" target="_blank"><img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1qfBPzljjNVWU63CZa1QQyhH9EfitWKC4" alt="my 
    product landing page"></a>

        <p class="project-title">Product Landing Page</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      <div class="project">
        <a class="project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/creativecodepenuser/pen/rNWVKGm" target="_blank"><img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1rSpKw5GcZg49gbxn7ISavvK_AYe6ADdW" alt="my survey 
    form"></a>

        <p class="project-title">My Survey Form</p>
      </div>

      <div class="project">
        <a class="project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/creativecodepenuser/pen/RwoPozb" target="_blank"><img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1tqpgUvJ1ntYR-uPv0QTs8X3TZnGQBk25" alt="my 
    tribute page"></a>

        <p class="project-title">My Tribute Page</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you please add your css to the snippet here on stackoverflow and clarify what the problem is.

Comment: try display: block for the .project-title

Comment: @katwhocodes that doesn't solve the problem. I just tried it.

Comment: my typo was not correct, it should be .project-tile, not .project-title. I tried to put .project-tile { display: inline-block; } , it was working

Comment: @katwhocodes I just found out that the only problem was the nav-bar width. I just fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

FYI: when I posted this question, the nav-bar width was set to about 80%, while the nav-bar itself was only 25% of the screen width. The only problem was the nav-bar width spanning across the image links. I only needed to make the width of the nav-bar 378px to solve the problem.